# Git hook to write current repo URL to a file

Tags: git

I am in a bit of a strange situation here. We are using a third party tool to package software. It uses git internally to checkout a list of git URLs but does so without getting the .git directory. Just like an npm git dependency. Meaning we lose the revision of the modules it packages which makes dependency tracking a nightmare.

The git URLs it uses are our internal URLs so we are in complete control of the repositories it clones

The problem I am trying to solve is to determine the git URLs used for each of the module it checks out.

My idea is (I'm welcome to hear alternatives) whenever we commit and push to a repository it activates a hook that opens a text file at the root of the git repository and writes the URL (especially if it is a tag) as well as the current revision. This way when the packaging software checks out this module it will also receive this text file showing where it came from.

Thanks

Comment: If it really downloads using git, then the marking file wouldn't be included in the clone — you would have to track it like any other file.

Comment: If I commit to module A and have a git hook to write a file to module A post commit. Then when the package manager clones module A it will also bring down this file with the URL in. The file being committed to module A with URL info will be added and tracked by git

Comment: Won't you spam your history this way? In the end it's not much different if the dev always increases the version manually or using a local hook.

Comment: Yeah it will spam good point. Tbh I only really need it when a tag is made of the repo as untagged revisions shouldn't be released anyway. That would help history a lot. Is this possible?

Comment: I don't know, would have to try with an update hook and a fake user to do the committing.